# convert regular number to an array reference to use it with the formula MATCH

Tags: excel-formula

I use excel 2019.

Is it possible, for example, to convert a cell that have the value 5 where 5 is a row number , to an array reference for row number 5:5 so that Excel recognizes it as an array reference rather than a regular number?

cell "A5" has the value 5, where 5 is the row number that I want the formula MATCH to search in

cell "A4" has the value "Cantaloupe, casaba, fresh", where this value that I want formula MATCH to search for

cell "B5" has the value "Fresh guava"
cell "C5" has the value "Papaya fruit, natural"
cell "D5" has the value "Cantaloupe, casaba, fresh"
cell "E5" has the value "Melon, cantaloupe, fresh"

[image: Visualisation of cells]

I want to search the value in cell "A4" in all columns of row 5.
The resulting value is 4 which is col number of cell "D5"

I tried the following formulas to replace the array 5:5 but didn't work

```
    =MATCH(A4;A5;0) 
    =MATCH(A4; {A5} ; 0) 
    =MATCH(A4; A5 & ":" & A5 ; 0)
    =MATCH(A4; { A5 & ":" & A5 } ; 0)
    =MATCH(C4;ROWS(A1:A300);0)
```

None of them succeeded.

It only worked with this formula: `=MATCH(A4;5:5;0)`, which is difficult to deal with.

Comment: Look into `INDEX()`

Comment: The suggestion to look at `INDEX()` is nice, but: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjyjc.png  (using: `=MATCH(A4,INDEX(A5&+":"&A5,1,,1),0)`) returns:  `#VALUE!` (In Excel2013)

Comment: @Luuk the syntax for your example would be: `=MATCH(A4,INDEX(B:G,A5,),0)` which returns 3 (3rd column starting from B)

Comment: Yesssss P.b this is the correct formula that does the job, your answer is excellent and appropriated